# Select updated records in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I select Ids of updated records in mysql;

Is there any way to do something like this

```
select Id from (update tblA set col1=false where col2 > 5 )
```

Comment: It will remain unclear unless you explain your requirement through some sample input and expected output.

Comment: How about:  `select * from tblA where col2 > 5`?

Comment: i want update and then select id of updated records

Comment: Removed invalid tags, improved gramar

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to select them before updating.

If your table uses InnoDB storage engine, use SELECT FOR UPDATE to lock selected rows and prevent other clients from inserting, updating or deleting selected rows.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM tblA WHERE col2 > 5 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tblA SET col1 = false WHERE col2 > 5;
COMMIT;
```

Another alternative is to set some column to a value which is unique to your client (e.g. process id) and when select using that value.
But it requires an additional column.

```
UPDATE tblA SET col1 = false, process_id = 12345 WHERE col2 > 5 AND process_id IS NULL;
SELECT id FROM tblA WHERE process_id = 12345
```